# sending dynamic html email containing javascript via a python script

Tags: javascript, python, email, bokeh, smtplib

1. at the first place, I could not help myself with the correct search terms on this.
2. secondly, I couldnt pretty much make it working with standard smtplib or email package in python.

The question is, I have a normal html page(basically it contains a  that is generated from bokeh package in python, and all it does is generating an html page the javascript within renders a nice zoomable plot when viewed in a browser.

My aim is to send that report (the html basically) over to recipients in a mail.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but you'll not be able to send an email with JavaScript embedded. That is a security risk. If you're lucky, an email provider will strip it before rendering, if you're unlucky, you'll be sent directly to spam and the provider will distrust your domain.

You're better off sending an email with a link to the chart.

Comment: Thanks man, demystified the air. Wish I could upvote your answer but I am unable to. Also, then what is the way I can make others skim through the insights and plots ? via a flask  / tornado server as usual?